# How would I return a row of information with certain cell values excluded from the results?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a schedule built with names of employees and areas they are working, using the columns as the days of the pay period. However, it is cluttered with information such as military leave, vacation days, FMLA, etc. I want to duplicate the data set but exclude those special occurrence days, so I get a clean schedule as to who is working and where they will be.

Editable Sheet is located here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cGpQE8wHc9X0Y2RVxgD0oozTbXLFOF08xoDklFkuhNM/edit#gid=0

Spreadsheet Visual[image]

```
=IF($A15<>"",FILTER(E6:AF13,A6:A13=$A15),"")
```

I've used the above formula, and it returns the entire row of info, I just don't know how to exclude the "MIL," "VAC," and "FMLA" entries from coming in, which is the goal.

Comment: Please share an example of your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

*Hoping this is the expected output you are looking for...*

```js
=ifna(filter(if(regexmatch(E$6:AB$13,"MIL|VAC|FMLA"),,E$6:AB$13),A$6:A$13=A25))
```

[image]

Comment: Just trying to clarify... 1) Cell:`A25` does this contain something like `={A6:A22}`? 2) `A$6:A$13=A25` Do you have to copy the formula down into each row?

Comment: 1, I mean I do not know if the names in the target area(lets say *A25:A32*) are going to be in the same order(or count_size) as in source area (*A6:A13*) in reality. So I just amended the existing formula OP added to the post. 2, yes its a drag-down formula

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative:

Enter this formula in Cell B3 (based on the sample shown below):

`=map(Sheet1!E6:AB22,LAMBDA(e,IF(OR(e="VAC",e="FMLA",e="MIL")," ",e)))`

- The raw data is on Sheet1
- The sample output is on a separate sheet. You can format this however you wish. In this case:

  - The dates in Rows 1&2 have been copied from the raw data
  - The list of names has been copied from the daw data
  - Conditional formatting applied for all blank cells

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: sample]